# pdfbox incorrect header check with pdf version 1.3

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

is there a known issue in Apache PDFBox with PDF version 1.3? If I want to extract texts from a pdf document with header 1.3 I get an exception:

```
java.util.zip.DataFormatException: incorrect header check
```

PDF files with version 1.4 and 1.5 are working. If I convert the PDF file manually with an external tool from version 1.3 to 1.4 it works too.

Here is the code I am using:

```
final PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(fileName));
parser.parse();
cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
final PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
pdfStripper.setAddMoreFormatting(true);
text = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc).trim();
```

I am using Apache PDFBox 1.8.10

Thanks!

**!!! Fixed !!!**

It looks as if there is a bug in 1.8.10. I updated the framework to version 2.0.6 and it works now.

Comment: Current version is 1.8.13 / 2.0.6. "incorrect header check" often happens if a PDF is empty; if not, please share your PDF. And you can simplfy your code by calling PDDocument.load(file) or PDDocument.loadNonSeq(file).

Comment: Glad to see it works. Consider deleting your question or answer it yourself.

Comment: In my case I can't update the the framework, because some stuff doesn't work in the new version.

Comment: Hmm, in my case everything works. Do you checked out the migration guide which explains alternatives for deprecated APIs?
https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if there is a bug in `1.8.10`. I updated the framework to version `2.0.6` and with the same PDF file it works now.